# ipython %run testscript_in_pythonpath.py returns "no file found" error

Tags: file, find, ipython, pythonpath

I would like to use the %run magic command to run a script in a directory which is in the pythonpath variable. The script reads some files in the working directory. However, when I try to run the script using the command: %run "testscript_in_pythonpath.py ", it returns an error. I thought files in pythonpath would be accessible to the interpreter, no ??

Comment: I just used the command: "import testscript_in_pythonpath". The script executed as normal although an "ImportError" was thrown saying no module was found. However, the command served the purpose. Now if there was a better way for doing this, it would be just fine!

Comment: Pythonpath is for libraries, not scripts. You can `%run -m testscript_in_pythonpath` to run it from its module name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Reposting as an answer)

`$PYTHONPATH` is what Python uses to look up modules to import, not scripts to run.

To run a file from `$PYTHONPATH`, you can do `import testscript_in_pythonpath`. Or, in IPython:

```
%run -m testscript_in_pythonpath
```

The difference is that if the file has an `if __name__ == '__main__':` section, `%run` will trigger that.

From a system shell, you can do the same thing as:

```
python -m testscript_in_pythonpath
```